# Amazon Kinesis: Get total number of consumers and producers for Amazon Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm started to work with Amazon Kinesis streams and faced with such issue - are there any options how can I get amount of producers and consumers currently connected to the stream? I looked for it in Amazon web console and checked out Kinesis documentation, but didn't find anything useful.

I worked previously with some other message brokers like RabbitMQ and it has pretty easy options for getting such information. Is there at all such ability for Kinesis?

Comment: Kinesis streams aren't connection-oriented. (SQS is the same way). Kinesis can't tell/doesn't track whether two subsequent puts or gets are from the same producer/consumer or from two different ones.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Do the [metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html) not provide some insight into what might be going on?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot in my case I has pipeline with few producers and few consumers connected to one Kinesis stream. And I had the issue when not all messages got to endpoint (it's DB which populated by consumers). So I investigated the cause of issue and tried to determine in which place exactly I had bug. As one of assumptions I thought there were troubles with connection to stream some producers or consumers. That's why I'm interesting how to know exact amount of connected items.